# how to set background image to be on the same place when resizing the page

Tags: css, background-image

I want to set background on the whole page but when I am resizing the page image is changing its position. The image is with height of 3065px so this is not the problem.

```
  .bg {
  background-image: url("#");
  height: 3065px;
  width: 100%; 
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: Well, your width 100% is the issue here, since the div resizes so is the background, try `background-size: 100% 100%;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (both height and width on your background-image):

```
bg. {

          /* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);

  /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Background image doesn't tile */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
  background-color: #464646;

}
```

Comment: This way image is repeating. When I add background-repeat: no-repeat; the image is no full size (not covering the whole page).

Comment: see revised answer.

Comment: This doesn't really answer's the op question, as you can see with the div resizes the background moves along with it, what you did is cut off parts of the background to fit the div width and then stretch in it,  easily fixed with just `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: Still not working. I don't want to be fixed. It is full page in this way but there is only one part of the image that is visible. I want the whole image to be visible.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: wight - 1024px height - 3065px